# Solution for localbroadcostmanager is causing a deprication warning

Tags: android, mqtt, paho, localbroadcastmanager

I have an android Studio app trying to implement MQTT. The example I am modifying uses androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager but it is deprecated.  I am trying to replace this with something else but I can't find any good examples.
Here is the code that I use.

```
build.gradle //(module)
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0'
}
```

in JavaClass

```
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;


  private void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(MqttServiceConstants.CALLBACK_TO_ACTIVITY);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(myContext).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        receiverRegistered = true;
    }
```

This seems to be the only place it is used.

I'm sorry if what I have here isn't enough but I am new to this and could use a lot of help.  Just let me know what more you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I just remove the

`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance`

from the code and use just

`myContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);`

it works just fine.